# Is there an app/feature to save comments

Tags: discussion, comments

Is there some kind of app or feature to save comments for posting? I noticed people posting the exact same comments to different questions. Something like this is common:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

I heard someone talking about such an app or feature. I forgot where I saw it. Just wondering if this is something SE/SO offers, or if this is some third party app. Or even if someone has some other technique for this beside the the lame copy and paste from some text file.

Comment: That is an automated comment that users can choose from when deleting / recommending deletion from the Low Quality Posts review queue.

Comment: As animuson said, these comments are automated comments from review queues. But there *is* an app for comments: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116/25384)

Comment: @animuson That was just an example. I see users with different comments

Comment: @peeskillet: ... he's telling you what it is and where it comes from.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Just to have an answer to this...*

There is an app - [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/25384) - which allows you to save a few comments for insertion with the press of a button.

---

Additionally, [the low quality review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) has a few comments you can post when marking a post for deletion: (including the one you mentioned)

> - This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
> - Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.
> - This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).
> - If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.
> - While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.